# Apache failed at step NAMESPACE

Tags: apache

Error occurs after the package updates

> apache2.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: Permission denied

Comment: This is a problem with unprivileged containers with newer version of systemd. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74804457/4970442)

Answer (score 12):

1. Connect to the server via SSH.
2. For the service unit set `PrivateTmp` to false.

   For Debian 8: Edit `/lib/systemd/system/apache.service`  and add

   ```
   [Service] 
   PrivateTmp=false
   ```
3. Start apache service

Comment: Serverfaults would be a better venue for this, but upvoted none the less. My service file was apache2.service. After modifying it I needed to run systemctl daemon-reload, before starting server.