# Apache2: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied

Tags: linux, apache, debian, vps, permission-denied

I have VPS server with Debian 10. I want to start Apache2 with option `PrivateTmp=true`.
But on start it failed with error: **apache2.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: Permission denied**.

```
    ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-27 17:17:43 CET; 5s ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 523 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[523]: apache2.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied
Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[523]: apache2.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: Permission denied
Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 27 17:17:43 5091-server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I checked the permissions for tmp:

```
root@5091-server:~# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 4096 Nov 27 17:17 /tmp
root@5091-server:~# ls -ld /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Nov 27 17:17 /var/tmp
```

Any idea which permissions are wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is related to new systemd security features (v220+?) conflicting with [unprivileged LXC containers](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Linux_Container#pct_settings) like the ones inside Proxmox.

1. Edit apache config (the clean way):

   ```
   sudo systemctl edit apache2.service
   ```
2. Add this to disable new systemd security features (affect LXC containers like the ones inside Proxmox)

   ```
   [Service]
   PrivateDevices=false
   PrivateTmp=false
   ProtectControlGroups=false
   ProtectKernelModules=false
   ProtectSystem=false
   ```

   [Maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187036/4970442) only necessary:

   ```
   ProtectHome=false
   ProtectSystem=false
   ```
3. Then

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl start apache2.service
   sudo systemctl status apache2.service  # Just to check the output
   ```

I saw this on apache2 and memcached. Also with systemd-logind. In this last case ssh connection speed was affected. `ssh -vvv` was stuck on `debug1: pledge: filesystem` (without VPN), and `debug1: pledge: network` (with VPN). As mention [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/p723ww/slow_login_to_bullseye/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716844/209677) the problem is solved enabling [nesting](https://ostechnix.com/enable-nested-virtualization-in-proxmox/) (also [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Linux_Container#pct_configuration)) on the Proxmox containers.

Probably simply enabling the "nesting" feature for the container (if it is unprivileged) will allow systemd to make use of its namespacing features.

### Related

- [Nested containers in LXD | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/blog/nested-containers-in-lxd)
- [Roadmap - Proxmox VE 7.1](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Roadmap#Proxmox_VE_7.1) The real fix is to upgrade host?
- [Failed to reset devices.list...Operation not permitted · Issue #2004 · lxc/lxd](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2004#issuecomment-217762235)

Comment: Specifically, running `pct set <CTID> --features nesting=1` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can work...

```
sudo sed -i -e 's,PrivateTmp=true,PrivateTmp=false\nNoNewPrivileges=yes,g' /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in docker with systemd on newer OS versions. My use case is a testing setup.

As it turns out, my host system for docker had apparmor enabled and this restricted the systemd usage inside the container.

I ended up using

```
    security_opts:
      - "apparmor=unconfined"
```

in the ansible molecule.yml.

The setting can be checked by running
`$ docker inspect $CONTAINERNAME --format '{{ .Id }}: SecurityOpt={{ .HostConfig.SecurityOpt }}'`